# Order a list of dictionary in Python with numeric keys

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of arrays that contains a dictionary in python. Here there is my example:

```
[[(0, 1), 'up'], [(1, 2), 'right'], [(3, 2), None], [(0, 0), 'up'], [(3, 0), 'left'], [(3, 1), None], [(2, 1), 'up'], [(2, 0), 'left'], [(2, 2), 'right'], [(1, 0), 'left'], [(0, 2), 'right']]
```

What I need to do is to order it base on the key (x, y) first on x and after on y: is it possible?

Here there is what I want as output:

```
[[(0, 0), 'up'], [(0, 1), 'up'], [(0, 2), 'right'], [(1, 0), 'left'],[(1, 2), 'right'], [(2, 0), 'left'], ....]
```

I have tried using that code:

```
s = sorted(s, key = lambda x: (x[0][0][0], x[0][0][1]))
```

But it returns:

```
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: `x` is the list element then you need just sort on tuples so you need `x[0]` no much deeper :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going too deep in the subscripting. In your case just sort on the tuple, the lexicographical order of the tuple suits your problem:

```
sorted(s,key = lambda x : x[0])
```

or without `lambda` with `operator.itemgetter`:

```
sorted(s,key = operator.itemgetter(0))
```

result:

```
[[(0, 0), 'up'], [(0, 1), 'up'], [(0, 2), 'right'], [(1, 0), 'left'], [(1, 2), 'right'], [(2, 0), 'left'], [(2, 1), 'up'], [(2, 2), 'right'], [(3, 0), 'left'], [(3, 1), None], [(3, 2), None]]
```

The interesting thing about this dataset is that you cannot use `sorted(s)` without a key because of your last argument, which can be a string or `None`.

On those particular values, it seems to work, but in the case of a tie (2 identical tuples, and the other terms being a string and `None`), `sort` would have compare the string and `None`, and that doesn't work in Python 3.

But could be solved by using a key function like `lambda x : (x[0],x[1] or "")` so if `x[1]` is `None` it changes it into an empty string and the comparison works (if `None` should be first, else use `lambda x : (x[0],-(x[1] is not None),x[1] or ""` to put `None` after any string).

Comment: If tuples were contain string like ('0', '0') , will this work, or should specify `key = lambda x: (x[0][0], x[0][1]))`?

Comment: what you're stating is the same as `x : x[0]` you're rebuilding the tuple.